# Overlaying two histograms with different rows using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to create a plot with two overlaying histograms for two normal distributions.

For example:

```
dist1 <- rnorm(1000, 35, 3)
dist2 <- rnorm(1200, 40, 5)
```

The thing is, as you can see, the distributions have different number of rows.

When you try to overlay this two histograms this pops an error.

Neither you can rearrange both distributions in the same data frame because of the same reason.

I thought about filling the smallest distribution with NULL values, but this seems to bring more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a "long" data.frame and plot that with ggplot2:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
dist1 <- rnorm(1000, 35, 3)
dist2 <- rnorm(1200, 40, 5)

df <- data.frame(variable = c(rep("dist1", length(dist1)), 
                              rep("dist2", length(dist2))), 
                 value=c(dist1, dist2))
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, fill=variable))+
    geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

You could also consider density plots, as they are easier to overlay:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, fill=variable))+
    geom_density(alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used **data.table** and **ggplot2**.

Please, have a look. The trick is to have the two objects in one `data.frame`.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dist1 <- rnorm(1000, 35, 3)
dist2 <- rnorm(1200, 40, 5)

dt1 <- data.table( id = rep("dist1", length(dist1) ),
                  dist = dist1 )
dt2 <- data.table( id = rep("dist2", length(dist2) ),
                  dist = dist2 )

dt <- rbindlist( list( dt1, dt2 ) )

ggplot( dt, aes( x = dist, fill = id ) ) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = .3)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>